# Saída muito inconstante em aplicação multithread juntamente com exception

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Estou vendo threads agora e fazendo umas experiências. É um teste simples, quero imprimir no console dez vezes o nome de cada thread inserindo em um mesmo objeto do tipo `List` de maneira sincronizada (uma acaba a outra começa).

O problema é que meu programa fica dando a exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` com uma saída muito inconstante. Uma hora imprime os nomes das threads de maneira correta, e no final a exception, outra nem imprime na tela os nomes.

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadsTeste {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TarefaAdicionaString obj = new TarefaAdicionaString();
        List<String> lista = obj.getLista();


        Thread thread1 = new Thread(obj, "Thread - 1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(obj, "Thread - 2");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
            System.out.println(lista.get(i));
        }



    }

}
```

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;


public class TarefaAdicionaString implements Runnable{

    public List<String> lista = new Vector<String>();

    public List<String> getLista(){
        return this.lista;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this){
            for(int i=0; i < 10; i ++){
                this.lista.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());              
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A operação `System.out.println` é bastante lenta. Você faz uma sequência de 100 instruções `System.out.println(lista.get(i));` na thread principal, e portanto fora da `thread1` e da `thread2`. A thread 1 vai acrescentar 10 elementos na lista e a thread 2 vai acrescentar outros 10. O resultado é que haverão 20 elementos. Logo, a thread principal vai fatalmente obter um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` quando `i` for igual a 20.

A ordem das inserções é indeterminada em relação aos `System.out.println`, logo é possível que você tenha um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` antes que os 20 itens sejam inseridos na lista. Aliás, uma vez que a thread principal provavelmente chega no `for` bem antes de qualquer uma das threads auxiliares iniciarem, o resultado mais provável é que ele dê `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` logo de cara na posição 0, que foi o que me aconteceu com **todos** os testes que fiz do seu código sem modificá-lo.

A ordem em que as threads serão iniciadas é indeterminada. Observe que como ambas as threads `thread1` e `thread2` sincronizam no mesmo objeto dentro do `run()`, você vai ter primeiro todos os 10 elementos de uma dessas threads na lista e depois os 10 elementos da outra thread. Mas nunca aparecerá eles entrelaçados/alternados.

Todos os testes que fiz acrescentando um `Thread.sleep(10);` antes do `for` da thread principal tiveram o comportamento de exibir primeiro os 10 itens da `thread1`, depois os 10 itens da `thread2` e depois o `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

O fato de às vezes ele travar, é um indício de que um deadlock ocorre. No entanto, olhando o código, não vejo como um deadlock seja possível e não consegui simular nenhum realizando apenas alterações mínimas no seu código.

Comment: E qual seria uma opcao mais segura pra que a execption não apareça?

Comment: @LucasMarinzeck O código que você deu é um problema muito "artifical", então é difícil dizer qual seria a melhor abordagem a ser naturalmente explorada no seu problema real. Entretanto, o mais provável é que a melhor solução seja trocar o `for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) { System.out.println(lista.get(i)); }` por `for (int i=0; i < lista.size(); i++) { System.out.println(lista.get(i)); }` ou melhor ainda, por `for (String x : lista) { System.out.println(x); }`.